# ARM template Parameters

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Currently, all parameters passed to a template are hardcoded (for instance, Windows Vm Version: 2012-Datacenter, 2016 Datacenter and so on). is their a way to dynamically update these values based on the type of subscription or the location?

Answer (score 0):

As I known, there is no in-build feature for you to dynamically update parameter values based on the type of subscription or the location. You could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager). In order to achieve this purpose, I assume that you need to add your code logic to generate the `TemplateParameterFile` based on the type of subscription or the location of your resource group, then leverage [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603823.aspx) command to deploy your Azure resources. Moreover, here are some common ARM templates, you could refer to [them](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates).

Comment: Hi Bruce,
Thanks for the response. I understand that it is doable using powershell, but wanted to check if there's any way to put it in the JSON template itself ( Documentation is a bit messy so :D )
And I see that someone has already posted a request for such functionality   [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/11677053-support-functions-within-the-definition-of-paramet)

Comment: I have voted for [it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/11677053-support-functions-within-the-definition-of-paramet), you could vote for it and wait for the feedback.